# How do I send rich text through XML to AEM 6.1 forms API?

Tags: xml, xsd, aem

I'm *very* new to AEM and don't even know if this is possible (at least in 6.1). We're using it to generate PDFs through the API from XML files. Our forms until now have been very simple, but now I need to process one that includes rich text. I've set the template field format that I care about to Rich Text (instead of Plaintext), but I can't figure out how to get rich text into it.

I've created a data connection in Designer using an XML schema. The content I need to send comes from outside AEM; I can capture it as markdown, xml, html, whatever.  But anything I put in the XML comes across as simple text.  Markdown doesn't seem to be supported in 6.1, rtf attributes are taken as literal values, and obviously I can't put html tags in my xml. The forms server is a corporate resource that I have little control over (I can change some settings but I don't know what they mean).

My .xsd file is mostly string elements. I've tried adding an element of type html (also tried text/rtf) per the Adobe documentation:

```
    <element name="test"> 
        <complexType> 
            <simpleContent> 
                <extension base="string"> 
                    <attribute ref="contentType" fixed="text/richtext"/> 
                </extension> 
            </simpleContent> 
        </complexType> 
    </element>
```

The new element was processed as plain text. Is there a way to send some kind of formatting in one element that AEM forms can translate?

Comment: It's not about xsd, it's about AEM. See if it allows you to insert your data into a [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section.

Comment: I tried putting html, rtf, and even plaintext in a CDATA section. Everything inside it was just ignored. I based my .xsd on [Adobe's documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/AEMForms/6.1/DesignerHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb-2c86b9dd129b8b0115c-7fb3.2.html), but I don't see anything there about how to format the XML used as input.

Comment: Your xsd does not look like the one in the docs. An attribute has namespaces declared `<xsd:attribute ref="xfa:contentType" fixed="text/html"/>`